# Generic extraction from a constructor

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

In F# and OCaml I wind up writing a lot of code like

```
type C = Blah of Whatever  
let d = Blah (createWhatever ())  // so d is type C  
...  
let x = match d with | Blah b -> b
```

What I'd like is this

```
...  
let x = peel d
```

Where peel would work for *any* constructor/discriminator.
Surely I'm not the only one annoyed by this.
edit:
Good answers, but I don't have the rep to vote on them.
How about this situation?

```
member self.Length = match self with | L lab -> lab.Length
```

Comment: It didn't when first posted, but indenting four spaces works now.  Weird.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to do that safely : if `peel` was a function, what would be its type ? It cannot be typed and therefore cannot be a "good guy" in the language.

You may :

- use reflection (in F#) or type-breaking functions (in OCaml it's the `Obj` module), but you will get something unsafe with an imprecise type, so it's rather ugly and "use at your own risk"
- use metaprogramming to generate different versions of `peel` at each type for you. For example, using the [type-conv](http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html#type-conv) OCaml tool, you may have `type blah = Blah of something` define a function `peel_blah` implicitly, and `type foo = Foo of something` define `peel_foo`.

The better solution imho is... not to need such a `peel` in the first place. I see two possibilities:

- You may use clever patterns instead of a function : by using `let (Blah whatever) = f x`, or `fun (Blah whatever) -> ...`, you don't need an unpacking function anymore.
- Or you may, instead of writing `type blah = Blah of what`, write

  `type blah = (blah_tag * whatever) and blah_tag = Blah`

  This way, you don't have a sum type but a product type (you write `(Blah, whatever)`), and your `peel` is just `snd`. You still have a different (incompatible) type for each `blah`, `foo` etc, but a uniform access interface.

Comment: Re: your first sentence, it's type would be `'a -> 'b` of course! :-)

Comment: I didn't know you could do `let (Blah whatever) = `  but it works!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, the `let` is convenient to do a pattern matching.
If you want to access the value in the middle of an expression, where patterns are not allowed, I suggest adding a member to the types:

```
type C = Blah of int
with member c.Value = match c with Blah x -> x

let x = Blah 5
let y = Blah 2
let sum = x.Value + y.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this instead:

```
type C = Blah of Whatever  
let d = Blah (createWhatever ())  // so d is type C  
...
let (Blah x) = d
```

For your second situation, I like Laurent's `member x.Value = match x with Blah v -> v`.

Answer (score 0):

Works for DUs...will need tweaking to work with class constructors:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let peel d = 
    if obj.ReferenceEquals(d, null) then nullArg "d"
    let ty = d.GetType()
    if FSharpType.IsUnion(ty) then
        match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(d, ty) with
        | _, [| value |] -> unbox value
        | _ -> failwith "more than one field"
    else failwith "not a union type"
```

By the way: I wouldn't typically do something like this, but since you asked...