# Getting values from a union case

Tags: f#

i have something like

```
type A = 
   | X of string
   | Y of int
```

i have a sequence of X types, `[X "foo"; X "boo"; X "moo"]`
is there a shortcut for doing a map to convert it to `["foo"; "boo"; "moo"]` without doing a match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't generally use a solution that doesn't handle all cases of the pattern matching (e.g. when using `fun (X str) -> ...`. It is always a good idea to add handler, even if it just reported a more informative error (such as, that the case was unexpected because it was filtered before).

You can extend kvb's solution using the `function` syntax (which is like `fun` with pattern matching):

```
List.map (function (X s) -> s | _ -> failwith "Unexpected case")
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to ignore `Y` values (so that `[X "a"; Y 1; X "b"]` becomes `["a"; "b"]`) you can use `List.choose` function:

```
List.choose (function (X s) -> Some s | _ -> None)
```

To write this using list comprehensions, you'd need to use full-blown pattern matching using `match`, so it would be a bit longer than using higher-order functions.

Comment: @Thomas, these are exact solutions that i've come up with as well :), actually, i can't use partial match because we set it to be an error instead of a warning, i was hoping that there was a shortcut, like id for fun i -> i or something like that where i could just map the inner value, but ended up using the List.choose function.

Comment: @Alex - Yes, it feels like there could be a syntax saying that a body (e.g. in a list comprehension) should be executed only for elements for which the pattern matches (so, ignore elements that don't match instead of throwing an exception).  But, unfortunately, there isn't... You could define that behavior using computation expressions, but you'd still get the warning (so it wouldn't really help that much).

Comment: Interestingly, a normal for loop with with a partial match will filter instead of fail (although it still gives a warning).

Comment: @Stephen - That's an interesting inconsistence.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
List.map (fun (X s) -> s)
```

This does perform a match behind the scenes, but the syntax is nicer.  You'll get a warning since the pattern is partial (that is, the function clearly won't be able to handle `Y _` instances).

Answer (score 3):

Just for grins, you could do this:

```
let get<'T> = function
  | X s -> box s :?> 'T
  | Y i -> box i :?> 'T
```

To get a list of `X` or `Y`, but not both.

```
[X "foo"; X "boo"; X "moo"] |> List.map get<string>
[Y 0; Y 1; Y 2] |> List.map get<int>
[Y 0; X "boo"; Y 2] |> List.map get<int> //oh snap!
```

If you're okay with boxed values, this works for mixed lists:

```
let get = function
  | X s -> box s
  | Y i -> box i

[Y 0; X "boo"; Y 2] |> List.map get //no problem
```

I'm assuming you're interested in unorthodox solutions since you're asking how to avoid pattern matching. ;-)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681490/generic-extraction-from-a-constructor/5681686#5681686) is another general-purpose, yet baroque, solution.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @kvb's solution, you can use a list comprehension with an incomplete pattern match:

```
let xl = [X "foo"; X "boo"; X "moo"]
[for X s in xl -> s]
```

Comment: If you use `s`, like kvb, instead of `str` your solution is 5 chars shorter. ;-) +1

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the tip, I modified for the shorter solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You must match. If you do that a lot, define functions getX and getY:

```
let getX (X v) = v

let getY (Y v) = v
```

But be aware that they will raise exceptions if given a value of the wrong case.